# Does the game end after the last boss?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

I would like to clear all mini bosses and not sure if I have this option after ending the game's main story.

So here is the question:

Is it possible to continue playing and fight mini-bosses after the final "story"-boss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you beat the final boss of your route, you don't go straight to new game+. You can continue to play until you choose to go to ng+ at the dilapidated temple idol.
[source](https://www.pcgamesn.com/sekiro-shadows-die-twice/sekiro-new-game-plus-changes)

Comment: Be careful though, IIRC progressing the main story may close sidequests, and you cannot meet all bosses in a single play-through.

Comment: For that matter, once you beat the last boss, you don't have to actually "end" the game. You can go back and save and presumably go exploring.